# How to retrieve Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart in code

Tags: magento-1.9, api

In the magento API how can I retrieve the "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" for a specific product?

I know for the min qty allowed its `$_product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();`   I tried getMaxSaleQty but that doesn't appear to be it.

Comment: try to print upto var_dump($_product->getStockItem()->getData())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out

> $_product->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty();

was correct. I had an issue elsewhere.

Comment: so issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

on [ce-1.5.1.0] getStockItem() doesn't return an object.  However `Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($magentoProductModel)->getMaxSaleQty();` does work.